# CKEditor android formatters work incorrectly

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, ckeditor

I have CKEditor v. 4.3.1 for my app. I tested it on android tablet - everything works fine, but when I've tried to enter text via CKEditor in android mobile phone, there was an issue that when I press format buttons(bold, superscript, etc.) they don't work, but when I press space button and then press format buttons, they work normally. (Android v 4.4.4, chrome v.37)

Has anyone faced the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future if you need to report a bug in CKEditor, it's better to do this on [CKEditor issue tracker](https://dev.ckeditor.com). Always make sure to provide as many details as possible, including the exact steps that you perform etc.

We did some testing and your findings are correct:
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12537
Can you add an addittional information to the ticket whether you are using stock Android 4.4.4 or e.g. Cyanogenmod?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't post it there, because I wasn't sure whether it is bug of CKEditor or not(may be android or something else).